# One UIViewController, can be delegate for one pickerview and for a an animated view at the same time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, delegates

I have one mainViewController that is also a delegate for a pickerview contained in the mainView.

I have also another view that contains a coverflow. I want to add the coverflow to my main view and make the mainViewController it's delegate. I do not know if it is possible. I used the following with no success:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource,
                                UIPickerViewDelegate, FlowCoverViewDelegate>
```

I do not know if it is only a syntax problem or what I need to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what is coverflow :) But for declaring MainViewController as a delegate you need to use something like this:

```
@interface MainViewController: UIViewController<UIPickerViewDelegate, AnyOtherDelegate1, AnyOtherDelegate2, AnyOtherDelegate3>
```